# Why does Hydra not stop when it finds a password?

Tags: brute-force, password-cracking, hydra

Why does Hydra 8.1 not stop when it finds a password?

I am using the `-P` option with a file that has over 5 Million passwords in it and the correct SSH password is located at approx. line 2100, but Hydra v 8.1 goes past that password and keeps going, and it looks like it is trying to process the entire file.

I have tried both, the `-F` and the `-f` option, which per the documentation, indicate that Hydra should stop when it finds a match.

Here is the command I am using:

```
hydra -f -V -t 10 -l admin -P ../../all ubuntu14vm ssh
```

If I actually use the following command with `-p` option instead, the command finds the password right away.

```
hydra -f -V -t 10 -l admin -p admin ubuntu14vm ssh
```

Only when I use the `-P` command with a file that contains the password, it seems that Hydra tries that password and keeps going and attempts to process the entire file.

Comment: You've asked the developer himself - I'm not sure how we can help you: Issue #55 https://github.com/vanhauser-thc/thc-hydra/issues/55